# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'user' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to react. I'm trying to use the jwt login methods from a template I downloaded. It's throwing this error and I'm clueless any help would be appreciated.

**AuthHooks.js**

```
// ForJWT Auth
import {getUserFromJwtAuth} from './helper/AuthHelper';
import {
  useJWTAuth,
  useJWTAuthActions,
} from '../services/auth/jwt-auth/JWTAuthProvider';

export const useAuthUser = () => {
  const {user, isAuthenticated, isLoading} = useJWTAuth();
  return {
    isLoading,
    isAuthenticated,
    user: getUserFromJwtAuth(user),
  };
};

export const useAuthMethod = () => {
  const {signInUser, signUpUser, logout} = useJWTAuthActions();
  return {
    signInUser,
    logout,
    signUpUser,
  };
};
```

**JWTAuthProvider.js**

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {
  FETCH_ERROR,
  FETCH_START,
  FETCH_SUCCESS,
} from '../../../../shared/constants/ActionTypes';
import jwtAxios, {setAuthToken} from './jwt-api';

const JWTAuthContext = createContext();
const JWTAuthActionsContext = createContext();

export const useJWTAuth = () => useContext(JWTAuthContext);

export const useJWTAuthActions = () => useContext(JWTAuthActionsContext);

const JWTAuthAuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [firebaseData, setJWTAuthData] = useState({
    user: null,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isLoading: true,
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAuthUser = () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

      if (!token) {
        setJWTAuthData({
          user: undefined,
          isLoading: false,
          isAuthenticated: false,
        });
        return;
      }
      setAuthToken(token);
      jwtAxios
        .get('/auth')
        .then(({data}) =>
          setJWTAuthData({
            user: data,
            isLoading: false,
            isAuthenticated: true,
          }),
        )
        .catch(() =>
          setJWTAuthData({
            user: undefined,
            isLoading: false,
            isAuthenticated: false,
          }),
        );
    };

    getAuthUser();
  }, []);

  const signInUser = async ({email, password}) => {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_START});
    try {
      const {data} = await jwtAxios.post('auth', {email, password});
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
      setAuthToken(data.token);
      const res = await jwtAxios.get('/auth');
      setJWTAuthData({user: res.data, isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false});
      dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
    } catch (error) {
      setJWTAuthData({
        ...firebaseData,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false,
      });
      dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
    }
  };

  const signUpUser = async ({name, email, password}) => {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_START});
    try {
      const {data} = await jwtAxios.post('users', {name, email, password});
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
      setAuthToken(data.token);
      const res = await jwtAxios.get('/auth');
      setJWTAuthData({user: res.data, isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false});
      dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
    } catch (error) {
      setJWTAuthData({
        ...firebaseData,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false,
      });
      dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    setAuthToken();
    setJWTAuthData({
      user: null,
      isLoading: false,
      isAuthenticated: false,
    });
  };

  return (
    <JWTAuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...firebaseData,
      }}>
      <JWTAuthActionsContext.Provider
        value={{
          signUpUser,
          signInUser,
          logout,
        }}>
        {children}
      </JWTAuthActionsContext.Provider>
    </JWTAuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default JWTAuthAuthProvider;

JWTAuthAuthProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};
```

Currently it's throwing error  TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'user' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined. on the line

```
const {user, isAuthenticated, isLoading} = useJWTAuth();
```

Comment: _`const JWTAuthContext = createContext();`_  you're initialising your context with nothing / `undefined` so why would it contain properties `user`, `isAuthenticated` and `isLoading`?

Comment: @Phil, Thanks, I'm new to react, no clue how context works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least to initialize the `JWTAuthContext` context with an empty object.

```
const JWTAuthContext = createContext({});
```